# TensorFlow: How to validate on 1 specific row of data and train on the rest?

Tags: python, pandas, validation, tensorflow, neural-network

I have 11 rows of data, and my goal is to train the network on 10, and validate on 1 specific row (not random).

The aim is to work through validating on each single row while training on the other 10, until I have a prediction for all 11 rows.

`x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1)`

The train/test split as shown above doesn't seem like it will work as it is random, is there a way to specify exactly which rows are to be used for training and testing?

Comment: You can use pandas slicing for extracting the only row you wish to train on using the index of that specific row

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for seems to be k-fold cross validation. This will use each row as a validation set, and train on the remaining k - 1 rows and so forth. I would suggest using sklearn's built-in method.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

n_splits = 11
for train_idx, test_idx in KFold(n_splits).split(x):
    x_train, x_test = x[train_idx], x[test_idx]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_idx], y[test_idx]
    # do your stuff
```

Comment: Thank you I think this is what I need, but how would I show the accuracy of training and validation for each instance? At the moment I can only work out how to show one instance.

Comment: In your training loop, just add a validation statement at the end of each epoch. If you're using TensorFlow 1, this just amounts to a `sess.run(..., feed_dict={...})` with the appropriate dataset fed in. I'm not very experienced with TF2, so I would read the documentation, but I'd assume you just add a validation metric and run that at the end of your training loop.